# Очиски памяти при обработке pcap-пакета

Tags: c++, linux, память, pcap, libpcap

Я пишу программу для анализа pcap-файлов. Программа должна использовать минимум памяти. Задался вопросом какой из способов перебора пакетов самый оптимальный по памяти:

1. Использовать pcap_ex, который (как я понял), не очищает память после обработки, и использовать memcpy

   ```
    while (1)        
   {
    l_numPkts = pcap_next_ex(pcap, &header, &pkt_data);
    //do something
     memcpy(dst,pkt_data,size);    
   }
   ```
2. Использовать pcap_loop

   ```
    pcap_loop(pcap, 0, func, NULL)

   void func(u_char *temp, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *data)
   {
   //...
   }
   ```
3. Или лучше заморочиться и написать собственную функцию?

Я пока не очень хорошо разбираюсь в этой теме. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: пакеты с файла снимаете или с интерфейса?

Comment: с файла  (pcap_open_offline)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эти функции просто двигают курсор по файлу замаппив его через `mmap`. Память дополнительно не выделяется. А вот за выделением памяти в  dst ( `memcpy(dst...`) нужно следить самому.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap